# reload cell data in table view with Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, reload

how is it possible to reload data for a cell in my table view? I want to do a request to my Server and the server responses JSON. At the moment I implemented the request and the response handling and I can show the data in my cells. But I want that the server only responses maybe ten datasets. When I scroll to the end of the table view with my ten cells in the app I want to do the next request to my server and the server delivers the next ten datasets and so on. I work with Swift as the programming language.

THX!

Comment: you can get Array of visible Cell by using TableView Function tableView.visibleRows() or You Can Get IndexPath of Visible Rows By  tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows() ! and then you can reload table by tableView.reloadData() Function!

Comment: look at this example https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `self.tableView.reloadData()` in order to reload your entire table or `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)` in order to reload a specific cell.

You can read more about the UITableView class [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html)

Comment: yes - that's why the code I gave is in swift... I'll add the "self." just to make sure.

Comment: I too use `self` to indicate it's an ivar ;) for me that makes it much more clear.

Comment: @YogevSitton self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)...I have tableView from which I want to add a new cell at 0 index....How can I do that, I mean..I not getting how to create a indexpath object with specific row and column, as there is no constructor of that type?

Answer (score 12):

To reload visible cells of tableview in Swift 3.0

```
pTableView.beginUpdates()

pTableView.reloadRows(at: pMessagesTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)

pTableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this...

Swift 2.0

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
   self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Swift 3.0

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: If you're calling reloadData() inside of a block, you have to dispatch it so that it's on the main_queue

Answer (score 4):

you can get Array of visible Cell by using `TableView` Function `tableView.visibleRows()` or You Can Get `IndexPath` of Visible Rows By `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()` ! and then you can reload table by `tableView.reloadData()` Function!

look at following links

[link1](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

you can read about `UITableView` Class [Here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html)